# Informatica Source Qualifer override failing

Tags: informatica

i'm trying to use the following function in the source qualifier query. This works in ORacle 19c SQL developer but when using it SQL query override is causing issues.

regexp_substr(col_name,'(.{0,40})\s')

do i have to handle any of these special characters in above function.

Tried different Escape characters but with no luck.

Comment: What issues is it causing? Is there an error message? Please update your question with the full SQL override statement

Comment: What are you trying to substring? Idea is, if it works in DB, the SQL override should work. But sometime it wont! so pls share  full SQL and error message.

Comment: Informatica doesnt allow some special characters like ' in source qualifier override, so we replace ' with CHR(39). Wondering if there is any list of special characters allowed and disallowed.

Comment: I’m not sure that is true. As long as the SQL override is a valid SQL statement for your source, it can contain any characters. However, without you updating your question with the full override statement it’s difficult for anyone to help you